# Data in column is running off the page , how can it be contained / wrapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap 3.x.x. Not that I have a lot more data. I'm just now seeing these rows shooting across the page.
Here is a Fiddle of it

https://jsfiddle.net/m562283y/

So since it is dynamic,  I'm not going to obviously know when to insert **br tag** and those are just bad ...

The TD column looked like this

```
<td class="ng-binding">00000006,00000005,00000007,00000008,0000000B,0000000D,0000000F,00000010,00000011,00000012,00000013,00000014,00000015,00000016,00000017,00000018,00000019,0000001A,0000001B,0000001C,0000001D,0000001E,0000001F,00000020</td>
```

Is the some responsive way to get the wrapping?

[image]

```
<div class="ui-view ng-scope"><div class="panel panel-primary ng-scope">
    <!--<div class="panel-heading" style="font-size:large">Baker Beach Device Registry
        </div>-->

    <div class="panel-body">

        <!--<div class="alert alert-info">
            <p>Sort key: {{sortKey}}</p>
            <p>Reverse: {{reverse}}</p>
            <p>Search String : {{search}}</p>
        </div>-->
        <!--<div class="row">-->

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form class="form-inline ng-pristine ng-valid">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Search</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
            </form>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>

                                <th ng-click="sort('DeviceId')">Device ID
                                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon glyphicon-chevron-down ng-hide" ng-show="sortKey=='DeviceId'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                                </th>
                                <th ng-click="sort('DeviceStatus')">Device Status
                                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon glyphicon-chevron-down ng-hide" ng-show="sortKey=='DeviceStatus'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                                </th>
                                <th ng-click="sort('StagedManifestIdList')">Staged Manifest
                                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon glyphicon-chevron-down ng-hide" ng-show="sortKey=='StagedManifestIdList'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                                </th>
                                <th ng-click="sort('ManifestIdList')">Archived Manifests
                                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon glyphicon-chevron-down ng-hide" ng-show="sortKey=='ManifestIdList'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                                </th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <!-- ngRepeat: device in vm.devices|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:7 --><tr ng-repeat="device in vm.devices|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:7" class="ng-scope">
                                <!--Add in sref directive-->
                                <td><a ui-sref="deviceDetail({DeviceId: device.DeviceId})" class="ng-binding" href="#/devices/00022BBA000000200001">00022BBA000000200001</a>
                                </td>

                                <!--<td>{{device.DeviceStatus}}</td>-->
                                <td ng-style="set_color(device)" class="ng-binding" style="color: orange;">Unactivated</td>
                                <!--<td ng-style="{'color':(device.DeviceStatus>1?'red':'blue')}">{{device.DeviceStatus | deviceStatus }}</td>-->
                                <td class="ng-binding"></td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">00000002,00000001,00000003,00000004</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="deviceEdit.info({DeviceId: device.DeviceId})" href="#/devices/edit/00022BBA000000200001/info">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: device in vm.devices|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:7 --><tr ng-repeat="device in vm.devices|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:7" class="ng-scope">
                                <!--Add in sref directive-->
                                <td><a ui-sref="deviceDetail({DeviceId: device.DeviceId})" class="ng-binding" href="#/devices/00022BBA000000220001">00022BBA000000220001</a>
                                </td>

                                <!--<td>{{device.DeviceStatus}}</td>-->
                                <td ng-style="set_color(device)" class="ng-binding" style="color: orange;">Unactivated</td>
                                <!--<td ng-style="{'color':(device.DeviceStatus>1?'red':'blue')}">{{device.DeviceStatus | deviceStatus }}</td>-->
                                <td class="ng-binding"></td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">0000000A,00000009,0000000C,0000000E</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="deviceEdit.info({DeviceId: device.DeviceId})" href="#/devices/edit/00022BBA000000220001/info">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: device in vm.devices|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:7 --><tr ng-repeat="device in vm.devices|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:7" class="ng-scope">
                                <!--Add in sref directive-->
                                <td><a ui-sref="deviceDetail({DeviceId: device.DeviceId})" class="ng-binding" href="#/devices/00022BBA000000210001">00022BBA000000210001</a>
                                </td>

                                <!--<td>{{device.DeviceStatus}}</td>-->
                                <td ng-style="set_color(device)" class="ng-binding" style="color: green;">Activated</td>
                                <!--<td ng-style="{'color':(device.DeviceStatus>1?'red':'blue')}">{{device.DeviceStatus | deviceStatus }}</td>-->
                                <td class="ng-binding"></td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">00000006,00000005,00000007,00000008,0000000B,0000000D,0000000F,00000010,00000011,00000012,00000013,00000014,00000015,00000016,00000017,00000018,00000019,0000001A,0000001B,0000001C,0000001D,0000001E,0000001F,00000020</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="deviceEdit.info({DeviceId: device.DeviceId})" href="#/devices/edit/00022BBA000000210001/info">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: device in vm.devices|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:7 --><tr ng-repeat="device in vm.devices|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:7" class="ng-scope">
                                <!--Add in sref directive-->
                                <td><a ui-sref="deviceDetail({DeviceId: device.DeviceId})" class="ng-binding" href="#/devices/00022B9E000000060001">00022B9E000000060001</a>
                                </td>

                                <!--<td>{{device.DeviceStatus}}</td>-->
                                <td ng-style="set_color(device)" class="ng-binding" style="color: blue;">New Device</td>
                                <!--<td ng-style="{'color':(device.DeviceStatus>1?'red':'blue')}">{{device.DeviceStatus | deviceStatus }}</td>-->
                                <td class="ng-binding">00000022,00000023</td>
                                <td class="ng-binding"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="deviceEdit.info({DeviceId: device.DeviceId})" href="#/devices/edit/00022B9E000000060001/info">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: device in vm.devices|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:7 -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <dir-pagination-controls max-size="5" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true" class="ng-isolate-scope"><!-- ngIf: 1 < pages.length --></dir-pagination-controls>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!--</div>-->
    </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: It's required that you post a minimal example of the markup/code that shows the problem here, not a third-party site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one.

Comment: Your code has to go in the question or your question is off-topic here. Questions are not allowed to depend on links to 3rd party code-hosting services like JSFiddle, the reliability of the 3rd party service is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table layout needs to be fixed. Put in the following css:

```
table{
  table-layout:fixed;
}

table td{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m562283y/1/)

Comment: don't custom style overrides feel a bit "hacky?"

Comment: When you use css frameworks, there can be conflicts and in order to solve those, you need custom css. So no, it doesnt feel 'hacky' to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution if you don't want really tall columns: https://jsfiddle.net/pm0e03ab/

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
      overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: hiding the content may not be good idea if the content is important to show.

Comment: Somtimes the ellipsis is really nice -  I need to find out if the stakeholders are wanting to go with this route.   thx

Answer (score 0):

You can break the text like this...
Creating a class and styling it in css

example...

```
<div class="row-fluid"> <span class="span3">
          <h1 class="heading">Headingaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum...aaaaaaaaaaaah</p>
        </span>
 <span class="span6">
          <h1 class="heading">Headingaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        </span>
 <span class="span3">
          <h1 class="heading">Heading Like This</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        </span>
```

css.

```
.row-fluid {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution will be to make it scrollable. Though it is not appropriate for your case but it can be useful for other cases where the content is not too long. So, I am posting the scrolling solution too.

Just add the following class to the immediate div containing the table.

```
.scroll_overflow {
  overflow: auto;
}
```